# How to add documentation to custom functions in Power Query Custom Connector?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm building a custom connector for Power BI, and I'd like to add documentation to my custom functions. I have read the official documentation and a few blog posts about this. I can't see what is wrong.
What I have tried:

```
section CustomConnector;

// this the function that gets exposed to the UI
[DataSource.Kind="CustomConnector", Publish="CustomConnector.Publish"]
shared CustomConnector.Contents = () =>
    let
        source = Navigation()
    in
        source;

// This is my navigator
Navigation = () =>
    let
      objects = #table(
       {"Name",                "Key",                   "Data",                                                             "ItemKind", "ItemName", "IsLeaf"},{    
       {"Function1",         "GetFunction1",     GetFunction1(),                                                "Table",    "Table",     true}, 
       {"Function2",  "CustomConnector.Function2", (optional artist_id as text) as table => CustomConnector.Function2(artist_id), "Function", "Function",  true}}),
        NavTable = Table.ToNavigationTable(objects, {"Key"}, "Name", "Data", "ItemKind", "ItemName", "IsLeaf") 
    in
        NavTable;

// This is an example of the function I want to provide documentation for
GetFunction2 = (optional artist_id) =>   
    let 
       source = "https://www.example.com/",
       response = Json.Document( Web.Contents ( source, [RelativePath = path & artist_id]) )
    in
       response;

// now the custom type function
GetFunction2Type = type function 
        (             
            optional artist_id as text  
        ) as table meta 
            [
                Documentation.Name = "GetFunction2",
                Documentation.LongDescription = "This function returns a table with details about the artist.",
                Documentation.Examples = 
                {
                    [
                        Description = "This function returns a table with details about the artist.",
                        Code = "GetFunction2(6WCWkB4bsGX2HDsoyaQb6KyL)",
                        Result = "Source = #table(
                                                {
                                                  ""something"",   
                                                  ""something2""   
                                                }, {{},{})"
                    ]
                }
            ];

// This is where I replace the original type for the custom type.
[DataSource.Kind = "CustomConnector"]
shared CustomConnector.GetFunction2 = Value.ReplaceType(GetFunction2 , GetFunction2Type);

// and here is my DataSource.Kind record
CustomConnector = [

    TestConnection = (dataSourcePath) => { "CustomConnector.Navigation" },
    Authentication = [
        OAuth = [
            StartLogin = StartLogin,
            FinishLogin = FinishLogin,
            Refresh = Refresh,
            Logout = Logout
        ]
    ]
];
```

Important aspect from the docs: "Functions associated with a data source must have the same **required** function parameters (including name, type, and order). Functions for a specific Data Source Kind can only use credentials associated with that Kind.". 
I think I understood this.
Now here is how this appears on the navigator in Power BI:

[image: description]

This is the same as before I implemented the custom documentation functions. Nothing happened and it is working normally.

Can anyone spot some mistake I'm making?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://ssbi-blog.de/blog/technical-topics-english/writing-documentation-for-custom-m-functions-part3/) article describes the problem of simultaneously reflecting documentation for functions and parameters.  There is a link in the comments that this is a platform bug.